# Decrease variable by 1 Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<input type='text' maxlength='32' onkeypress='previewLength(32)'>
```

I want to decrease 32 with 1 each time a key is pressed

Im using this for a length preview (max length is 32 and each time a key is pressed it gets decreased by 1 and shows the user how much he has left)

```
<script>
function previewLength (maxLength) {
maxLength = maxLength -= 1;
document.getElementById('CounterLength').innerHTML = maxLength;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Tip: you can use shorthand writing: maxLength--; (this will decrease the value by 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some misconceptions, you'll want to look at the actual value, not the number of keypresses. For example: backspace, and arrow-left are also keypresses but they don't increase the length of the value.

html:

```
<input type='text' maxlength='32' onkeypress='previewLength(this, 32)'>
                                                            ^- use `this`
```

js:

```
function previewLength (input_element, maxLength) {
    var remain = maxLength - input_element.value.length;
    document.getElementById('CounterLength').innerHTML = remain;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The other answer was also very helpful but you were first.

Answer (score 2):

Use the length of the actual value instead of counting keypresses (as for example the backspace key would reduce the length instead of increasing it):

```
<input type="text" maxlength="32" onkeypress="previewLength(this.maxLength, this.value.length, 'CounterLength');">

<script type="text/javascript">
function previewLength (maxLength, actualLength, id) {
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = maxLength - actualLength;
}
</script>
```

(By also sending the maxlength and display element id into the function, it can be reused for multiple elements.)

Answer (score 0):

I would add some check not to show negative number, and just pass name of the control

```
window.updateCounter = function updateCounter(e, name) {
  var len = e.value.length
  , max = e.maxLength
  , remaining = (max - len) > 0 ? max-len : 0
  document.getElementById(name).innerHTML = remaining
}
```

markup

```
<input type='text' maxlength='32' onkeypress='updateCounter(this, "counter")'/>
<span id='counter'>32</span>
```